# How to update the ticket field using API

Tags: jenkins, zendesk, zendesk-api

Can someday jump on this and help me to update the ticket field (ticket is already submitted), the targeted field is a custom-field which I need to update it using the Zendesk [API,](http://www.hydrogenwatermaker.net)

Can this is possible using Zendesk API?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

### Update - Using Zendesk Api Endpoint

Zendesk Api [Update Ticket](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/tickets/#update-ticket) is what you need to hit with the payload as described [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/creating-and-updating-tickets/#setting-custom-field-values):

```js
    {
        ticket: {
            custom_fields: [{ "id": 25356371, "value": "something"}]          
        }
    }
```

#### Old Answer (using zafClient)

If you're trying this from Sidebar app and utilizing `zafClient` then its pretty straightforward. Example [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/apps/apps-support-api/ticket_sidebar/#set-2) and below

```
client.set('ticket.customField:fieldName', value)
```

If you're trying this with Zendesk rest api then you can utilize [this](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/tickets/#update-ticket) Update Ticket endpoint to update the value of any Custom-Field present in that ticket.

Steps to update:

1. get custom-field's id
2. get ticket id
3. Hit update ticket api with following JSON payload

```js
{
    ticket: {
        custom_fields: [{id: <custom_field_id>, value: 'hurray!'}]
    },
}
```

Comment: Note that in the first scenario (`zafClient.set`) the ticket won't be automatically updated — an agent needs to click the submit button in order for the field value to be preserved.

In the second scenario (Update Ticket API endpoint) the ticket will be updated with the field value right away.